# Who is the doer of a gerund?

Tags: gerunds

For example in the following sentences, who is the doer and how can we be sure?

**Swimming is good for him.** -- If I swim, is it good for him?

**Being elected president was a shock to him.**

**Having read the book once before makes me more prepared.**

**Being heavily committed to a course of action is likely to make an executive miss signs of incipient trouble.**

Comment: The word you're looking for is _subject_, not _doer_. Not every predicate is an action. Gerunds frequently have their subjects deleted, when the speaker thinks the listener can figure out who the subject is from context. Speakers are not always correct about this. In the sentences you give, the subject of _swimming_ is either _him_ or `Indefinite`; the subject of _being elected_ is _him_; the subject of _having read_ is _me_; and the subject of _being committed_ is either _an executive_ or `Indefinite`. As to certainty, we can't be sure; we just have to do the best we can.

Comment: This is one of the many cases in English of ambiguous reference, which can only be resolved pragmatically, not by any rules of syntax. Consider _Swimming is good for him_ vs. _Hanging is too good for him_.

Comment: @JohnLawler @.ColinFine Thanks guys! This helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

If one wishes to come to peace with English *gerunds* one will need bite a bullet.

One will pray for forgiveness and accept that a *gerund*

> ain't a verb.

An English *gerund*

> is a noun.

Tuck this away deep within you; do not go out in public and announce this reality. You might be charged with heresy if you do. An English *gerund* does not need a "doer". It is a noun.

> Swimming is good for him.

This sentence is no different than

> Pie is good for him.

except for a trade in nouns. "Pie" needs no "doer". "Swimming" needs no "doer", it is only the name (noun) of an activity.

Come to peace with this or risk becoming a *grammarian*. My opinion is that one will be happier and saner with the acceptance that a *gerund*

> ain't a verb.

I hope someone can explain this better than I; that is, without resort to mysticism that declares a *gerund* to be a verb that is a noun. One cannot even make a Trinity out of that.